# Codecov order by coverage percentage

Tags: code-coverage, codecov

I configured CI as `python -m pytest -v --cov-report term --cov=./src` and `codecov` after success.

I would like to get the final coverage order by (sorted by) `Cover` column in descending order (from 100% at the top and 0% at the bottom). However, I can not find such options.
Is it possible? I've taken a look at `codecov --help`, but also didn't help.

Is there any option to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the `Files` tab on the commit page in `Codecov`, you can view all the files in expanded by clicking the button on the top right corner. Then, just click on `Coverage` to sort by that field.

An open-source example:
https://codecov.io/gh/nodejs/node/list/289d6cf26f56e0d948dee7b3983228472bfb317d/

[Click the file-type selector to expand files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrtSw.png)

[Click coverage to sort by value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxlTB.png)